# phrase_prefix query returns empty result if I search for 3 characters but returns non-empty result if I search for 4 and more characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query :

```
"match": {   
    "_all": {
    "query": "ana",
    "type": "phrase_prefix"
   }
 }
```

This query does not return anything with phrase "ana" that is 3 characters length, but if I search for 4 characters phrase "anat" it returns result :

```
match": {
  "_all": {
  "query": "anat",
  "type": "phrase_prefix"
  }
}
```

What could be the problem here ? I have no idea why is that and how to solve this.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to [`max_expansions`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix) parameter being set to its default value of 10.

Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": {
        "query": "ana",
        "type": "phrase_prefix",
        "max_expansions": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try different values of "max_expansions", do not make it too large otherwise it will take time for query to return

Does this help?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This works with "max_expansions": 200. Is there any explanation for that ? I'm not doing this query with fuzzy , I just want to get exact match by the prefix. Thanks !!!!

Comment: [This](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-exactly-works-quot-max-expansions-quot-in-match-phrase-prefix-query-td4030146.html), will hep you, the way `max_expansions` works is, it tries to find values with given prefix in alphabetical order, so _anaa_, _anab_ etc.

Comment: Thanks,  this really helped. Do you think that max_expansion set to 150 or even 200 is not too big?

Comment: glad it worked for you, If you have huge index then it might take few milliseconds more, I dont think it is too big to cause any performance issues, I have set it to `100` in my own application and It works smoothly.You would get better Idea if you do some testing.

Comment: also It is weird that it does not give you any result for _"ana"_, how many words do you think you have that starts with _"ana"_ ?

Comment: At least I have one : "anatomy", but it found only if I query "anat" or max_expansion 200 with "ana"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97214/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-slavag).